# Linking R studio to C++ boost library (windows)

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I am trying to work out how to get boost to work on windows. I followed the instructions to install it via the visual studio command line.

When I try and compile a function in R I get this error

```
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/Me/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Me/fs-analytis/src"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c regex.cpp -o regex.o
regex.cpp:5:27: fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/regex.hpp>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: regex.o] Error 1
```

It sounds like something needs to be in the rtools folder perhaps but i am not sure

Comment: Can you use R package BH? https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH

Comment: In general you _cannot_ just mix C++ libraries compiled by Visual Studio with use by `g++` as from Rtools.  If you need Boost libraries _with linking_, recompile Boost with Rtools.

Comment: @Roland it might be possible but i get a large block of errors in R when i compile the C++ that say ```undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::put_mem_block(void``` amongst other things

Comment: Dear @Tiger_Stripes there is a difference between _header-only_ use (works for many but not all Boost libraries) and _linking use_.  Boost regular expressions _requires_ linking so you are out of luck.  That said, with C++11 you also get regular expressions so maybe take those.